# Changing kernel bootsplash image?

Tags: linux, boot, embedded, splash, beaglebone

I want to display a custom boot splash image on my Beaglebone Black (running Ångström).

I know of three places where images can be dumped to the framebuffer:

- Bootloader (uboot) - needs display initialization (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beagleboard/GwzL01ZHeC4) Looks generally hackish.
- Kernel - Displays a Tux penguin (for each core)
- User-space (e.g. psplash)

I want to avoid changing the bootloader if possible. I tried creating a userspace service, but systemd starts late in the boot process, leaving about 2secs of Mr. Tux and only about 1 sec showing my splash screen before I got to the login prompt.

Is there a way to replace the penguin with a custom splash screen (ideally without touching the bootloader or patching the kernel)?

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153975/how-to-change-boot-logo-in-linux-mint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can recompile the new logo in the kernel. These links may help:

[How to change the Linux penguin boot logo - ArticleWorld](http://www.articleworld.org/index.php/How_to_change_the_Linux_penguin_boot_logo)

[How to change your Boot Logo in Linux Kernel (Suman's World)](http://web.archive.org/web/20140707092448/http://sumanprasanna.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/how-to-change-your-boot-logo-in-linux-kernel)

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping there was an easier way (kernel args, etc), but it appears not.

Comment: Both links are no good. Suman's world article is no longer available and the tool recommended in the other link `fblogo`; the link they use for downloading it is no longer available as well. May need to update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this procedure to change the boot splash logo:

pngtopnm logo.png | ppmquant 224| pnmtoplainpnm >  logo_linux_clut224.ppm.

Then copy the file logo_linux_clut224.ppm to the directory of drivers/video/logo/ in the linux source directory, after backing up the original. Then compile the kernel. I have a few outdated links for clues and insight. Here are those links for reference:

http://www.articleworld.org/index.php/How_to_change_the_Linux_penguin_boot_logo

https://linuxlink.timesys.com/docs/wiki/engineering/HOWTO_Use_a_custom_boot_logo

Good luck.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).